# Debugging #AJAX and FormAPI

Tags: forms, ajax, debugging

What is the easiest way to view current `$form_state` variables while working with `#ajax`?

Is there a way I can get `dpm()` to update automatically on each AJAX load?

If it matters, I'm testing AJAX on a Node Submit form.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `dd($form_state);` within the callback function works beautifully.

On linux you can `tail -f /tmp/drupal-debug.txt` to see the `$form_state` in real time. (Or whatever the temp directory for your site is set to, often something like `sites/yoursite.com/files/tmp`.)

Otherwise, you can find drupal-debug.txt in your systems /tmp/ directory.
http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html#dd

Answer (score 8):

The best thing I've found:
https://drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log

Part of/depends on Devel and uses `ddl` to output anything in kpr fashion at admin/reports/debug.

Comment: This module is really useful - thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I was also having problems with finding a good way to debug AJAX with the Form API and found debugging with FirePHP to be the best solution:

http://www.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/how-debug-ajax-drupal-using-firephp

Answer (score 1):

You could also try with something like this, and looking into the response tab on FireBug:

```
function _exit($var) {
  print_r($var);
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome developer console can help a lot.

- Open the page where you fire up  the ajax call
- Open Chrome developers tools
- Click tab "Network"
- Click  the below "preview" tab
- Clean all current records
- Open a page with autocomplete field
- Fire up the ajax (IE: push submit buttom)
- Check output